# How to set the width of dropdown button and dropdown menu using "react-bulma-components" in React so their width fill the parent div?

Tags: reactjs, bulma

`<Dropdown>` in the code below includes a dropdown button and a dropdown menu that contains many dropdown items. When the dropdown button is clicked, the dropdown menu with those dropdown items will appear. It looks like this: [image]

Below is the code that achieves the effect in the image:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bulma-components";


class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card is-vcentered columns" style={{display: "block"}}>
                <section className="hero is-light is-small">
                    <div className="hero-body">
                        <div className="container">
                            <p className="title is-6 has-text-centered">Welcome to the Would You Rather App!</p>
                            <p className="subtitle is-7 has-text-centered">Please sign in to continue</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <figure className="image container is-128x128">
                    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49168480441_edbb9c3337_o_d.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div className="column is-full">
                <p className="title is-5 has-text-primary has-text-centered">Sign In</p>
                </div>
                <div style={{border: "1px solid", textAlign: "center"}}>
                    <Dropdown label={"Select User"} className="is-fullwidth">
                        <Dropdown.Item value="james">
                            James
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item value="bob">
                            Bob
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item value="alice">
                            Alice
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item value="carol">
                            Carol
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Divider />
                        <Dropdown.Item value="barron">
                            Barron
                        </Dropdown.Item>
                    </Dropdown>
                </div>
                <div className="column is-full" style={{margin: 0}}>
                    <button className="button is-primary is-fullwidth">
                        <strong>Sign In</strong>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card;
```

What I want to achieve is to stretch the "Select User" button and the dropdown menu so they have the width as the green button right below. I tried many stylings such as `style={{width: "100%"}}` but none of them worked.

Comment: As of now, it seems they have not given any functionality for the same. There is only one variable [$dropdown-menu-min-width](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/) in scss which might help you with the menu width but not with the select user button. For now, you can manually look out for classes and then override the css as per your needs

Comment: I've just started learning React. Your solution seems too hard for me but thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, in the react-bulma-components there is no such functionality (mentioned in their official docs) to increase the width for the `Select User` which you are asking for. You can only increase/decrease the width for the menu by using sass variable [`$dropdown-menu-min-width`](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/)

Since you are new to react, what you can try it to look out for the classes for the dropdown (open your inspector and look out for class="..." values). Then you can manually over-ride the properties by writing a new css something like this:

```
.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-trigger {
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have updated the same for you in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-aryabhata-kv9nw

and it gives the output of sort:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I copy your code, I can't achieve the effect right away. I need to add `column` after `dropdown-wrap`. The dropdown menu is left align but does not align with the dropdown in terms of width. I tried width by using `style={{width: 100%}}` but nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, it might have happened. I have written very simplified version here. If you are working in some project, other css might be conflicting with this one. You need to know what `css specificity` is and `how to override css`; then you can build up on the solution which I have given to achieve the result. If you are working on some sandbox/fiddle or place where you can make you source or even result available, I might be able help you out.

Comment: While your answer did not immediately solve my problem. It give me an inspiration that I can override the default styling in a custom css even when the className does not appear in my code. Therefore, I give you my approval. Thank you for your help!